# Android-Xamarin RelativeLayout Attributes not working

Tags: android, xamarin

For Android in RelativeView , some attributes arent working. It keeps saying they aren't declared. How do i fix this?

This is in VS community 2015 with Xamarin

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

That's fine. It will always say there are some errors but it will compile. I usually use Android Studio to edit those XML files and paste to VS. The VS designer is not as easy to use as Android Studio's.

But here Relative Layout do not have Orientation, that's for Linear Layout.